# how to read json file with a list of strings in python

Tags: python, json

Here is a sample of json data I created from defaultdict in python.

```
[{
    "company": [
        "ABCD"
    ],
    "fullname": [
        "Bruce Lamont",
        "Ariel Zilist",
        "Bruce Lamont",
        "Bobby Ramirez"
    ],
    "position": [
        " The Hesh",
        " Server",
        " HESH",
        " Production Assistant"
    ],
    "profile_url": [
        "http://www.url1.com",
        "http://www.url2.com",
        "http://www.url3.com",
        "http://www.url4.com",
    ]
}]
```

I realized I made a mistake creating such list. `json.loads()` gives this error

**Error**

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

I want something like this.

```
[{
    "company": [
        "name": "THALIA HALL",
        "employee": {
            fullname: "emp_name",
            "position": "position",
            profile: "url"
        },
        {
            fullname: "emp_name",
            "position": "position",
            profile: "url"
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to do this on python.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding an extra comma in the end for profile_url array. The proper json should be

```
[{
    "company": [
        "ABCD"
    ],
    "fullname": [
        "Bruce Lamont",
        "Ariel Zilist",
        "Bruce Lamont",
        "Bobby Ramirez"
    ],
    "position": [
        " The Hesh",
        " Server",
        " HESH",
        " Production Assistant"
    ],
    "profile_url": [
        "http://www.url1.com",
        "http://www.url2.com",
        "http://www.url3.com",
        "http://www.url4.com"
    ]
}]
```

Use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check for JSON formatting errors next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

j  = '[{"company":["ABCD"],"fullname":["Bruce Lamont","Ariel Zilist","Bruce Lamont","Bobby Ramirez"],"position":[" The Hesh"," Server"," HESH"," Production Assistant"],"profile_url":["http://www.url1.com","http://www.url2.com","http://www.url3.com","http://www.url4.com"]}]'


json_obj = json.loads(j)
```

you have your JSON as object and now you can user for making csv

Comment: I have around 2000 company info stored in a json file as shown in first snippet in my question. Actually I want to convert it into csv. How can I do that?